# Confusion between container heap and jvm heap in Apache Hadoop 2.7.x

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, out-of-memory, hadoop2

I have configured Apache Hadoop 2.7.x with 3 workers. I have faced some exception like

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

After some [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded), I have found that I should increase my JVM heap size. For this there are three parameters in hadoop namely `1. mapred.child.java.opts`, `2. mapreduce.map.java.opts`, `3. mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`. According to my understanding, the last two parameters are mapreduce jvm i.e., the jar that I created to run on hadoop. I have set these parameters about 0.8% of `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` and `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb` respectively.

Now the problem is what max value I can set for `mapred.child.java.opts` and where it is being used. Is this the problem that GC is reporting or map/reduce heap.

Also what is the relation of map-reduce JVM with container in context of resources i.e., memory especially. What max value I can give for `mapred.child.java.opts` in a similar way as for `mapreduce.amp.java.opts`; it should not be more that `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`.
I have reviewed a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156588/yarn-containers-and-jvm) but unfortunately It could not clarify my understanding.